# how to identify issue client side issue for Blazor server

Tags: blazor

I am playing around with blazor I have a few pages but I created one component page and ever time I navigate to it at the bottom of the page I have this Message: "An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details. Reload "
I check the dev tools and there isn't any errors in the console the same in the network calls details. Any Idea how to track down what is causing this? Also I am able to do all the functions without issue as well I can submit changes to the edit form.

Answer (score 1):

I did some more google search and the issue was I removed from the style sheet the hidding of the error message .
Added this back in the style.css

```
#blazor-error-ui {
    background: lightyellow;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.25rem 0.7rem 1.25rem;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#blazor-error-ui .dismiss {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.75rem;
    top: 0.5rem;
}
```